# VBA EXP file transformed to Excel file not allowing code to work

Tags: vba, excel

I hope you can help. The issue I am facing is this I have two pieces of code the first piece takes EXP files stored in a folder and transforms them into Excel files "xls" this piece of code is labelled CODE Piece 1 below.

This piece of code seems to work fine.

The second piece of code labelled CODE Piece 2 below. Allows a user to navigate to a folder select this folder then the code loops through all the files in this folder and deliminates the Excel files with | and then it should add new rows and columns. The issue is that the files deliminate no problem but the adding of rows and columns does not happen.

The odd thing is if I run this macro on workbooks that have **not** been through CODE Piece 1, Everything works fine the row and columns add.

But even if take out the deliminating part of the code and just just tell the macro to added the row and the columns and i run it on the files that have been transformed by CODE piece 1 again nothing. I don't get any errors, the macro runs but nothing happens.

If I even turn on the screen updating applications and I can see the macro doing its thing, adding the row and columns and saving the document but when I went to open the file back up i got the an error pop up (see error 1 below) once i clicked 'Yes' on the pop up the file would open but no added row or columns

I am at a loss as to how to solve this issue. I believe my coding is good but Ia m not getting the result I want. Can someone please advise.

As always any and all help is welcome.

CODE Piece 1

```
Public Sub Loop_Rename_Files_in_Folder()

    Dim folder As String
    Dim filename As String

    folder = "C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\Claire Macro\Reject Macro\Move Exceled\"               'MODIFY THIS LINE - FOLDER CONTAINING FILES TO BE RENAMED

    If Right(folder, 1) <> "\" Then folder = folder & "\"
    filename = Dir(folder & "*.exp")
    Do While filename <> vbNullString
        Name folder & filename As folder & Left(filename, InStrRev(filename, ".")) & "xls"
        filename = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

CODE Piece 2

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim rng As Range

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xl??*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
      With wb
      Set rng = Range("A:A")

    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:="|"
        Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
        Range("A:E").EntireColumn.Insert

      End With


    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Error 1 
[image]

Formatted
[image]

STUCK AS TXT

[image]

CODE that saves as new Workbook but leaves the corrupted Originals as is

CODE Piece 3

```
Sub OpenFiles()
'UpdateByExtendoffice20160623
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\GAP Reports\"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)



    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xl??")
    Do While xFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open xStrPath & "\" & xFile
    With wb
      Set rng = Range("A:A")

    rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:="|"
        Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
        Range("A:E").EntireColumn.Insert
        Range("A1").Value = "Source File"
        Range("B1").Value = "Reason"
        Range("C1").Value = "Action"
        Range("D1").Value = "Team"
        Range("E1").Value = "Status"


        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
      ActiveWorkbook.Close
      End With
        xFile = Dir

    Loop

      'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: have you reset wb once you have moved the file? It could be that the location has changed and then it would error.

Comment: Hi Lowpar: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I am unsure of your comment though . I am not actually moving any files. the files never move from `folder = "C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\Claire Macro\Reject Macro\Move Exceled\"` the files are EXP in this folder then the become XLS and then the CODE piece 2 loops through `folder = "C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\Claire Macro\Reject Macro\Move Exceled\"` The files never actually move.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the Workbooks in CODE Piece 1 as `.xlsx` instead of `.xls` (Win2003 Format). Also its enough to say `myExtension = "*.xl*"` for Excel Files. Your problem is when opening workbooks, that you dont address then worksheet correctly. Also what does `DoEvents` do? Its probably not necessary.

Code Piece 2 should look like this:

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String: myPath = ""
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim rng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xl*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myPath & myFile)
      Set sht = wb.Worksheets(1) 'First Sheet (adjust if needed)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue

      Set rng = sht.Range("A:A")

      rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, _
        OtherChar:="|"

        With sht
            .Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
            .Range("A:E").EntireColumn.Insert
        End With



    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi UGP. Thank you for taking the time respond. when i plugged your Code piece 2 into my macro I'm afraid the rows and the columns still don't get created. and I still get the pop up Error 1 as seen above. keeping your given code in place i then made the change in Code piece 1 `Name folder & filename As folder & Left(filename, InStrRev(filename, ".")) & ".xlsx"` putting .xlsx instead of .xls with this in place I ran code piece 2 and I got Error 1 again but this time in the VBA editor debugger as the run time error 1004. Thanks for the help but its still not giving me what i want back :-(

Comment: Could you add a picture how a file looks after formatting to xlsx?

Comment: I get both times Error 1004

Comment: Hi UGP. I added a pic of the formatting. as you can see the dilimination happens but not the row add or column add

Comment: HI UGP. I think the issue I am facing is that even though I have used code to turn and EXP file to XLS the file somehow still thinks its TXT as you can see in the pic STUCK AS TEXT i just added marked in blue at the top states xls circled in blue at bottom the dialog box it is text. its not fully transforming to xls?? is there something a miss in the code?

Comment: Yes, renaming, does not really convert it properly. What you could do is rename to `.xls` and then open and save them as `.xlsx` then they will be real excel files.

Comment: Yes I agree this is what I a have been attempting this morning but I am struggling with the code. Does this have to happen in Code piece 1 or 2?

Comment: I tried but didnt really work. File is still corrupted.

Comment: I know Its a real brain buster :-) I did mange a kind of ugly way around. With a different loop code. This does save the Excels as Excels but it creates brand new Excel Workbooks it doesn't actually turn the originals into actual Excel Workbooks. It will have to do. I have put the new code under the last pic if you wish to have a look. And thank you again for the help it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thats seems to be the only workaround. But i would not use ActiveWorkbook for both files you open and adress the sheet directly to minimize possible errors as you see in my code. Also the `with wb` does not do anything, there are no methods that use wb. Keep that in mind.